# ExtJS 4: grid: how to select a newly created record?

Tags: extjs, grid, selection, extjs4

My question is so simple it's in the title!

Here's my code:

```
userCreate: function(button) {
    var grid = button.up('panel'),
        store = grid.getStore();

    /* Create new empty record */
    var inst = store.add({})[0];
    store.sync();
    /* select the newly created record */
    grid.getSelectionModel().select(inst.id);

    Ext.create('GS.view.user.Edit', { create:true }); 
},
```

Now I just want the line after the

```
    /* select the newly created record */
```

to work!

I've tried many things but none of them work:

```
    grid.getSelectionModel().select(inst.id);
    grid.getSelectionModel().select(inst);
    grid.getSelectionModel().select(store.last);
```

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: I think it'll have something to do with the phantom flag on the record.

Comment: I've updated my question thanks to your comment. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found: ExtJS seems to be lost when there's no "id" field.
So after a call to `sync()` if you didn't precise an "id" field, it kindof re-organize the grid and can't find the "old" record (the one I remembered just before the call).
This is just what I guess, I may be wrong.

Anyway, I've made a turnaround: to stay "homogeneonous", I'm going to make `xxxCreate()`, and `xxxCreateValidate()`, same for `xxxUpdate()` and `xxxUpdateValidate()`. I've done them for the example: user => `userCreate()`, `userCreateValidate()`, `userUpdate()` and `userUpdateValidate()`:

```
init: function () {
    this.control({
        /* (!) Actions in 'userlist' */
        'userlist': {
            itemdblclick: this.userEdit
        },  
        'userlist button[action=create]': {
            click: this.userCreate
        },  
        'userlist button[action=delete]': {
            click: this.userDelete
        },  
        /* (!) Actions in 'useredit' */
        'useredit button[action=create]': {
            click: this.userCreateValidate
        },  
        'useredit button[action=save]': {
            click: this.userEditValidate
        }   
    }); 
},  

userCreate: function(button) {
    /* Using Ext.create() to pass variable create:true
     * instead of the shortcut:
     * var view = Ext.widget('useredit');
     */
    var view = Ext.create('GS.view.user.Edit', {
        create:true
    }); 
},  

userCreateValidate: function(button) {
    var win    = button.up('window'),
        form   = win.down('form'),
        values = form.getValues();

    this.getUsersStore().add(values);
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
    win.close();
},  

userEdit: function(grid, record) {
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},  

userEditValidate: function (button) {
    var win    = button.up('window'),
        form   = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();

    record.set(values);
    win.close();
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
},
```

I hope my code will help someone... now I'm looking for a way to handle keys in the Grid. And like everything with ExtJS: you don't spend your time coding, because everything is already done, you spend your time ***searching***... it's more frustrating actually =)

Anyway, the most important thing to note is that the newly added record is *not* selected. It's just a workaround to continue to develop, but it's not what I wanted (it's not exactly what I'm asking for in the question).

Comment: Sorry, but ... what does it have to do with your original quesion?

Comment: The solution is a workaround, to *not* use what I'm asking, i.e. avoid selecting a new record, and just create it. Maybe a workaround is not a good answer. If so, I apologize, and I'll remove my own answer. See the `userCreateValidate()` function which calls `sync()` but doesn't need to select the record once it has been created.

Answer (score 1):

like what @Tom said...
use grid view to select your new record, althougt
you can still select your new record via selection model...

from docs.. select method need 3 parameter to pass..
so in your case :

```
userCreate: function(button) {
    var grid = button.up('panel');
    store = grid.getStore();

    /* Create new empty record */
    var inst = store.add({})[0];
    store.sync();

    /* select the newly created record via model*/
    grid.getSelectionModel().select(inst, true, true);

    /* select the newly created record via view*/
    grid.getView().select(inst, true, true);

    Ext.create('GS.view.user.Edit', { create:true }); 
},
```

Comment: You are (almost) right. The `grid.getView().select()` was the right call to do (the one before is useless). But now the problem comes from `store.sync()`: if I call `store.synch()` the system can't find the record (it seems it kind of "looses" it). I'm getting closer, but not close enough. And I **need** to call `store.synch()` because the server sends back the default values, and I don't want the default values to be hard coded in my JavaScript code. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: could you update your question with your current code or use jsfiddle.net? cause, when i tried the function with my dummy grid (no server interaction).. it still works

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem here is that you try to select record right after you call `store.sync();` but this is actually asynchronous request that updates store after it gets data from server.

Try calling `grid.getSelectionModel().select` after your store is updated from server. Problem with this approach is that `store.sync` doesn't support any callback method, but you should be able to use `datachanged` event on your store, that should be fired after store synchronization is all done.

Try something like this (based on limited code sample you provided):

```
userCreate: function(button) {
    var grid = button.up('panel'),
        store = grid.getStore();

    /* Create new empty record */
    var inst = store.add({})[0];

    store.on('datachanged', function() {
        /* select the newly created record, keep existing selection and
           don't suppress events because grid view is updating upon this event
        */
        grid.getSelectionModel().select(inst, true, false);
        Ext.create('GS.view.user.Edit', { create:true }); 
    });

    store.sync();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Grid row selection is usually handled in the View object (in ExtJS 3 it was GridView). So I think if you update your code above to look like:

grid.getView().select(0);

This will select the row at index 0 which looks like where you're adding the new record. The View object will then notify the selection model and update the browser view. There are other selection options which you can find via the API docs at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.View-method-select

Answer (score 0):

Your example [**works fine**](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/puxM8/) when `grid.getSelectionModel().select(inst);` is being used. So the only thing that can cause such behavior is `store.sync();` throwing exception. Check out the console output for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of any possibility to directly select this record because before sync, that records is a phantom record in the store but not afterwards. Also, you might be assigning an id to it on the server side(?) which would change the record and it would'nt be the same after sync()...

If some field in the record is to be unique (e.g. name or description or anything), you might use that to find this record after sync and select it:

```
var value = store.getAt(0).get('name');           // getting the value of a unique field e.g. "name" from the newly added record

store.sync();

var rec = store.findRecord("name", value);   // find the record with the unique value "name" after sync
grid.getSelectionModel().select(rec);       // select that record
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use like this:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(store.data.length-1)
```

Comment: Fails when store is sorted